# Is it possible to send a first message on bootstrap of ActiveMQ part of configuration

Tags: activemq-classic, messagebroker

I'm trying to avoid sending a message in the application level. Because the message is special; It is just an empty message that I send to ActiveMQ which is later delivered after x minutes to clients (a way for maintaining a shared clock).

This is Schedule Message Delivery and is part of ActiveMQ features.

OK, back to the question, as could send the message scheduled for delivery to clients each x minutes:

```js
sendNotifications(
  { data: {} },
  {
    schedule: {
      cron: `*/5 * * * *`,
    },
  }
);
```

I try to avoid sending this message on app bootstrap but on configuration of ActiveMQ itself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to initialize a queue with a message configured via `activemq.xml` (or any other supported broker configuration file). You'll need to use an application to send this message.

Comment: Is there a way from client to delete a queue and recreate it ? This way I'm sure I can set my scheduler properly just one time

Comment: You should ask a new question about this. It's too complicated to explain in a comment.

Comment: Agreed, this has been done.